# How can I extract the value of a XML REST response tag using XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, rest, web-services, xslt

I have this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LookupResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/PT_Lookup.LookupResponse.V1">
   <ResponseComp xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/PT_Lookup.ResponseComp.V1">
      <RespVal>X</RespVal>
      <RespDescr>Deleted</RespDescr>
   </ResponseComp>
</LookupResponse>
```

How can I use XSLT to extract only the  value; ie "Deleted"?

I have no knowledge of this so all the docs I'm reading looks like greek to me, but being that I will be using it going forward, at least having some relevant piece of code would help me build upon it.

Comment: What format do you want the output in? Just the text? The text wrapped in some tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns just the text inside that tag (I did ask about format in a comment). Note that there's an assumption that there won't be multiple `<ResponseComp>` elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:n="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/PT_Lookup.ResponseComp.V1">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="n:ResponseComp ">
        <xsl:value-of select="n:RespDescr"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```